# Increment Knockout observable

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to increment observable variable with 1, but it can't process properly

JavaScript :

```
    self.fiscalYear = ko.observable(0);
    self.fiscalStartYear = ko.observable(0);
    self.fiscalEndYear = ko.observable(0);

    self.showYearsDetail = function () {
        self.fiscalStartYear(self.fiscalYear());
        self.fiscalEndYear(self.fiscalYear() + 1);
    };

    self.fiscalYear.subscribe(function () {
        self.showYearsDetail();
    });
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span2 display-label">Fiscal Year  </div>
        <input id="fiscalYear" type="text" data-bind="value: fiscalYear" placeholder="Fiscal Year">
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span2 display-label">Start Year  </div>
        <div class="span6 text-info"><span data-bind="text: fiscalStartYear"></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span2 display-label">End Year  </div>
        <div class="span6 text-info"><span data-bind="text: fiscalEndYear"></span></div>
    </div>
```

If i am insert 2014

output Start Year: 2014
       End Year : 20145

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try replacing this:

```
self.fiscalEndYear(self.fiscalYear() + 1);
```

with this:

```
self.fiscalEndYear(parseInt(self.fiscalYear()) + 1);
```

Comment: Is there an atomic way to do this?